# Redmine Installation - Reg

Tags: redmine

I need some help on the below.
I am Planning to switch my ticketing tool from `Fogbugz` to `Redmine`.
I have a few questions on that to be clarified, please assist.

1) Firstly what is the best suggestion to go for another ticketing tool.
We found this Redmine a few advantages like time tracking, `Gnatt chart`, `Open source(Free)`.
But I have tried a many times to install it to my machine, not successful.
I got a link from Bitnami Installation of Redmine. Looked simple and I am done.
Is this a demo, cannot we use as redmine, that is `Redmine` Vs `BitmaniRedmine.`?

2) Also is it possible to Import our Old data (From `Fogbugz` to `Redmine`). I found there are options but I am not very clear about.
Can Anyone assist me on this..?
Is there any best similar tool which will meet our needs...?
Please advise.

Venu Aravindan,
rvgaravindann@gmail.com

Comment: Venu:If you have money to purchase then atlassian jira is the best option.Or if you need open source then go for redmine.And please mention what error did u get during installation,which version is you are using and your Operating system also

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitnami or install on your own. 
Installation instructions are explained on Redmine website and in howto sections, as well as in books, like [Redmine Cookbook](http://packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/redmine-cookbook)

To import issues in Redmine, use issue import plugin:

1. export your Fogbuz issues in csv, xls or some other form
2. install Redmine plugin from https://github.com/gc-olivierho/redmine_importer (there are other plugins also available)
3. click on import and find issues exported from Fogbuz
4. Map the fields like (name, description etc...) from Fogbuz to Redmine